# Is it always safe to assume that values of ..stream::int_type are >= 0 except for eof

Tags: c++, stream

I want to parse a file and use an `std::stringstream` to parse its contents. I use `get()` to read it character by character, which yields an `std::stringstream::int_type`. Now in certain cases I want to use a lookup table to convert ascii characters into other values (for example, to deterime whether a certain character is allowed in an identifier or not).

Now can I assume that the values I get from `get()` are non-negative, unless it is `std::stringstream::traits_type::eof()`? (And hence use them as indices for the lookup tables).

I couldn't find anything in the standard regarding that, which might be due to a lack of understanding on my part how this whole bytes to characters thing works in C++.

Answer (score 1):

First let look at the more general case of basic_stringstream.

You can't assume that `eof()` is negative (I see the constraint nowhere and the C standard states *The value of the macro WEOF may differ from that of EOF and need not be negative.*)

In general, `int_type` comes from the trait parameter and the description of `int_type` for character traits doesn't mandate that `to_int_type` returns something positive.

Now, `stringsteam` is `basic_stringstream<char>` and thus use `char_traits<char>`; `eof` is negative but I haven't found a mandate that `to_int_type` has to non-negative values (it isn't in 21.2.3.1 and I see no way to deduce it from other constraints), but I wonder if I miss something as my expectation was that `to_int_type(c)` had to be equivalent to `(int)(unsigned char)c` -- it is the case for the GNU standard C++ library and I somewhat expect to get the same behavior as in C where functions taking or returning characters in `int` return non-negative values for characters.)

For information, the other standard specialization of `char_traits`:

- `char_traits<char16_t>` and `char_traits<char32_t>` have an unsigned `int_type`, so even `eof()` is positive;
- `char_traits<wchar_t>::to_int_type` isn't mandated to return a positive value for non `eof()` input either (but in contrast with `char_traits<char>` I didn't expect such mandate to be there).

Comment: `std::stringstream` is `std::basic_stringstream<char>` so uses `char_traits<char>` so the constraint "The member `eof()` shall return `EOF`." from [char.traits.specializations.char] applies and `EOF` is negative.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, oh, I though the question was about `std::basic_stringstream<char>` and thus gave a more general answer than needed, I've updated it.

Comment: Thank you so far for the answer. My problem though is less about the sign of `eof()` but rather the sign of the ASCII characters (which I want to use as indices for a lookup_table).